# I get a black screen in my game after I press the back button and resume

Tags: android, libgdx, dispose

I am using LibGDX to create a game. I have implemented `AssetManager` to load all the assets and also I created a class `GameSkin` that adds a lot of button styles and things like that to a skin so that I don't have to do it manually. Here it is:

```
public class GameSkin extends Skin {

private static final AssetManager ASSET_MANAGER = Assets.getAssetManager();
private TextureAtlas atlas;

private FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
private FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;
private BitmapFont defaultFont;

private TextButton.TextButtonStyle redButtonStyle, orangeButtonStyle, greenButtonStyle, blueButtonStyle, defaultButtonStyle;

private Label.LabelStyle labelStyle;

private Window.WindowStyle windowStyle, firstTimeWindowStyle;

public GameSkin() {
    Assets.load();
    ASSET_MANAGER.finishLoading();

    atlas = ASSET_MANAGER.get("uiskin.atlas");
    addRegions(atlas);

    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font/komika.ttf"));
    parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 100;
    defaultFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    generator.dispose();

    defaultButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    redButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    orangeButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    greenButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    blueButtonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();

    redButtonStyle.font = defaultFont;
    redButtonStyle.up = getDrawable("rbup");
    redButtonStyle.down = getDrawable("rbdown");

    orangeButtonStyle.font = defaultFont;
    orangeButtonStyle.up = getDrawable("obup");
    orangeButtonStyle.down = getDrawable("obdown");

    greenButtonStyle.font = defaultFont;
    greenButtonStyle.up = getDrawable("gbup");
    greenButtonStyle.down = getDrawable("gbdown");

    blueButtonStyle.font = defaultFont;
    blueButtonStyle.up = getDrawable("bbup");
    blueButtonStyle.down = getDrawable("bbdown");

    defaultButtonStyle.font = defaultFont;
    defaultButtonStyle.up = getDrawable("obup");
    defaultButtonStyle.down = getDrawable("obdown");

    labelStyle = new Label.LabelStyle(defaultFont, Color.WHITE);

    windowStyle = new Window.WindowStyle(defaultFont, Color.WHITE, getDrawable("GT"));

    firstTimeWindowStyle = new Window.WindowStyle(defaultFont, Color.WHITE, getDrawable("guide"));

    add("default-font", defaultFont);
    add("red-button", redButtonStyle);
    add("orange-button", orangeButtonStyle);
    add("green-button", greenButtonStyle);
    add("blue-button", blueButtonStyle);
    add("default", defaultButtonStyle);
    add("default", labelStyle);
    add("default", windowStyle);
    add("first-time", firstTimeWindowStyle);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}
```

}

This is how the welcome screen looks like:
[image]

And this is what happens after I press the back button to exit and then tap on the app to resume:
[image]

It seems that everything gets disposed (?) besides the BitmapFont that I use on the buttons, but I don't understand what is wrong with this. Anyone can help?

Comment: Don't use a static reference to your Assets or Textures. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets#creating-an-assetmanager

Comment: I used that and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your code is almost complete, this needs to go in your AndroidLauncher (reloads assets onResume):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Assets.unload();
    Assets.load();
    ASSET_MANAGER.finishLoading();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: This will cause unnecessary reloading every time the user task switches away and back to the app without closing the activity.

Comment: Indeed, see http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=19960&p=83364#p83364

Comment: This is all happening before the `resume()` method is called. I stopped using static variables and now it works.